# Bail out of an object's init with arc?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

How do I bail out of creating an object with ARC?

I'm looking for the ARC equivalent of this (from memory):

```
- (id)init
{
     if (( self = [super init] )) {
         if (!condition) {
             [self release];
             self = nil;
             return self;
         }
     }
     return self;
 }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just get rid of the call to `release` and you'll be fine. Since you nil self, there will be no more references to the old self so it will be deallocated.

```
- (id)init;
{
     if ((self = [super init])) {
         if (!condition) {
             return nil;
         }
     }
     return self;
 }
```

Comment: I was hoping this was the case, but it seemed too simple.

Comment: It's not necessary to assign `nil` to self either.  You can just say `return nil` and ARC will release the object.

Comment: Also, remove the `;` after `init` to actually make the thing compile. I'd also slightly change your wording in that there might be other references to that "self". `super` might have done something with it that retained it. But in general you're right that simply removing the `[self release]` makes it work.

Comment: Ah, found this in the LLVM docs: "Methods in the init family implicitly consume their self parameter and return a retained object. Neither of these properties can be altered through attributes." http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family.semantics.init

Comment: @matt The semicolon is (weirdly) legal. I think there's an SO question about that floating around...

Comment: @mattjgalloway `;` is actually allowed for Objective-C method bodies. Try it. Makes copying-pasting between .h and .m easier.

Comment: I'd use caution before starting it. As Josh points out, it's weird. And as you've pointed out, nobody expects it. But alas, it's too late for me. :)

Comment: No need to set `self = nil`? (I'm a bit confused here)

Comment: @ran, just imagine self is a local variable within the init method. This should suffice. Since, that local variable never sees light outside the function (we return nil;)

Comment: Or is it a variable in the caller's end, that gets assigned nil and hence released?